# What happens to an EventHandler after calling "new"

Tags: c#, handler, observablecollection

I have a little question and made up an example case:

```
 public class MyClass
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> PropertyA { get; set; }
    private ObservableCollection<string> PropertyB { get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        PropertyA = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        PropertyA.CollectionChanged += (sender, e) => DoStuff();
        PropertyA.Add("AAAA");

        PropertyB = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        PropertyB.Add("BBBB");

        MyMethod();
    }

    private void MyMethod()
    {
        PropertyA = new ObservableCollection<string>(PropertyB.Where('some linq expression'));
        //does PropertyA still have its CollectionChanged handler from here on?    
    }
}
```

As you might see from my comment the question is: Does the handler of my PropertyA still work after calling 'new' on the Property again? Or do I have to setup the handler again?

Comment: Of course not, how could it? They are two completely unrelated objects. Don't replace the collection, just change its contents.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set up the property handler for the new object "AAAA".

However, the original object will still exist in memory and won't get garbage collected as the event handler keeps the reference alive. This will cause resource issues if you let it continue. You need to remove the event handler from the object before it either falls out of scope or you overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to setup the handler again.

Internally you are storing the delegate in the field of the first `ObservableCollection` instance. Creating a new object means new values for its fields.

You can also test this fast:

```
private void DoStuff()
{
    Console.WriteLine("handler called");
}

var obj = new MyClass();
obj.PropertyA.Add("1");
obj.MyMethod();
obj.PropertyA.Add("1");
```

The  code will print "handler called" only once. (see live demo at https://repl.it/DKjs)

You can also update the collection instead of replacing it.

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    var newValues = PropertyB.Where(x => true);
    PropertyA.Clear();
    foreach (var value in newValues)
    {
        PropertyA.Add(value);
    }
}
```

This will print "handler called" multiple times (once per each collection update, including removing items, see live demo at https://repl.it/DKlF)